# How can I maintain the loyalty of my evil minions?

Tags: evil-genius

I've just had a number of my minions leave my evil organisation due to their low loyalty to me.

Why does this become low, and what can I do to increase it?

Comment: I appreciate this question, because the asker has taken time to carefully craft it in such a way that it could possibly be interpreted in a context outside the scope of Gaming. +1.

Comment: Sounds like you need some [incentives](http://www.theswain.com/Flash/Mastermind3.htm).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Losing Loyalty

- Body bags have an AoE that reduces minion loyalty.
- Overwork without recreation reduces loyalty.
- Minions with low attention can accidentally trigger traps. This can cause loss of loyalty depending on the trap.

### Regaining Loyalty

- Your avatar has an AoE that inspires loyalty. Make sure you always idle in a well-defended but minion-rich room such as the Control Room.
- Loot items have an AoE that increase loyalty. Place these in areas where your minions concentrate (control room, barracks, etc).
- Torturing an enemy agent (or another minion) will increase the loyalty of those who witness the act.
- Access to a Staff Room with appropriate equipment will keep a minion loyal.
- If you see someone deserting, you can capture them and throw them in a cell for a few minutes. They will become *very* loyal again.
- You can execute a minion to make those who witness the act very loyal.

Comment: Yup. Placing loot items in my control room and corridors pretty much solved all my loyalty issues.

Comment: Added to the "Losing loyalty" column: The Super Agent from the caribbean, Marina Mamba, has a special "attack" that zeroes out the target minion's loyalty, causing instant defection.

Comment: Here's a exploit to make sure that you capture a deserting minion (except for one converted by Maria Mamba): when you get the message that one has deserted, click on the message to jump to the minion. Tag them for capture, then double-click them. They will stop to salute you. Then right-click on the henchmen bar (selects your first henchman) and right-click on the minion. This will summon your first henchmen to capture them without moving your focus to the henchman. While waiting for your henchman to arrive, continually double-click on the minion, causing them to stop repeatedly to salute you.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to stop minions from deserting is to place treasure items in minion popular rooms, just make sure the treasure items are still defended. Another way is to build a few sentry guns at the front of your base and tag the deserter for capture by clicking on the bar that says who deserted. Then leave them in a cell.